# StackOverflow error in TextWatcher watcher in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, stack-overflow, textwatcher

I'm converting my amount text from `EditText` to a double format and im trying to remove to `","` in the `EditText` to execute my proper format for my computations. What's wrong with my code and having stack overflow?

```
// Gets the two EditText controls' Editable values

String cleanBasicTax;
if(txtBasicTax.getText().toString().contains(",")){
    cleanBasicTax=txtBasicTax.getText().toString().replace(",", "");
}
else{
    cleanBasicTax=txtBasicTax.getText().toString();
}

String cleantxtSurcharge;
if(txtSurcharge.getText().toString().contains(",")){
    cleantxtSurcharge=txtSurcharge.getText().toString().replace(",", "");
}
else{
    cleantxtSurcharge=txtSurcharge.getText().toString();
}

String cleanInterest;
if(txtInterest.getText().toString().contains(",")){
    cleanInterest=txtInterest.getText().toString().replace(",", "");
}
else{
    cleanInterest=txtInterest.getText().toString();
}

String cleanCompromise=txtCompromise.getText().toString().replace(",", "");
if(txtCompromise.getText().toString().contains(",")){
    cleanCompromise=txtCompromise.getText().toString().replace(",", "");
}
else{
    cleanCompromise=txtCompromise.getText().toString();
}           

Editable editableValueBasicTax = txtBasicTax.getText().replace(0, txtBasicTax.length(), cleanBasicTax),
    editableValueSurcharge = txtSurcharge.getText().replace(0, txtSurcharge.length(), cleantxtSurcharge),
    editableValueInterest = txtInterest.getText().replace(0, txtInterest.length(), cleanInterest),
    editableValueCompromise = txtCompromise.getText().replace(0, txtCompromise.length(), cleanCompromise);
```

Comment: No clue why stackoverflow happens but this code need review for sure. Why not declare `final String comma = ","; final String empty = "";` and `String cleanBasicTax = txtBasicTax.getText().toString();` `if(cleanBasicTax.contains(comma)) { cleanBasicTax = cleanBasicTax.replace(comma, empty); } else { .. } ` so on..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `TextWathcer` changes the text that it is watching, causing another call to the watcher, causing another change to the text, ... and so on until you run out of stack space invoking methods.

One way to fix it is to set up a `boolean` flag to `true` when you're running inside the watcher and return immediately if the flag is set to kill the recursion. In pseudocode:

```
boolean mIsInWatcher = false;

void onTextChanged(...) {
   if (mIsInWatcher) return;
   mIsInWatcher = true;

   // text modifications here

   mIsInWatcher = false;
}
```

Comment: i'm confused i call my computation  in afterTextChanged.. do you mean i need to transfer it to the onTextChanged..?

Comment: @DreamBigAlvin I change my code to onTextChanged() , nothing is so different for me..I think that is depending on your code,buddy..

Comment: @laalto Worked perfectly..Thz ..Take +1 for solving my error :) I tried to find at stackoverflow topics about that error a long time but I can't find solution..Now,I finally found solution..Really thanks..

Answer (score 2):

if you are calling a textView onTextChangeListener, and replacing text in the same method, you simply get into a loop, since replace will call the same method. And thus the error.

Try replace the text elsewhere.